# Using slow network emulation in VS2015

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to run my entire application and test it with a slow network connection. I've read a number of MS articles about setting up a .testsettings file, but its not clear on how to actually use it when I run the client.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: What have you tried? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have a look at [Configure Network Emulation Using Test Settings in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505008.aspx)

Comment: Fiddler doesn't look like it'll help as I need to be able to specify speeds like in the VS configuration page, not just a modem speed setting. I've already ben to the link above on configuring the network link emulation. Its good for what to set up, but not how to run it. I've realised I didn't state that the application is c# WPF and not web based at all, but just needs to connect to various remote services that I need to test across a number of connection speeds. I just want to run the full app with the selected speed, not a specific unit test.